# Angular: Getting data from child without event

Tags: javascript, angular

Using Angular 6 here. I have a page which has about 2 child components.
The first one has 2 input text and the second one has one dropdown. My parent component just has the button click.

I know I can use Eventemitter on my child component and pass the value to my parent but how shall I pass the value from my child if there are no button click events. I tried to user ViewChild which sort of works but there is a delay until the view is fully loaded. I am using ViewChild as below:

--Parent--

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from "../child/child.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    Message: {{ message }}
    <app-child></app-child>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child;

  constructor() { }

  message:string;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.message = this.child.message
  }
}
```

--Child--

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {

  message = 'Hola Mundo!';

  constructor() { }

}
```

I have taken the above ex from https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Could anyone provide inputs how I can achieve passing/reading data from child without having to use any button click/emitter.

--Updated--

--Child--

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-child',
  templateUrl: './child.html'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  childmessage: string = "Child Message!"
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

--Parent--

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit  {

  constructor() { }

    message: string;

  getDataFromChild(child1): void {
    this.message = child1.message;    
  } 


  ngOnInit() {}  
}
```

--Parent Html--

```
 Message: {{message}}
 <ct-child #child1></ct-metadata>
 <button type="button" (click)="getDataFromChild(child1)">Click Me!</button>
```

I have tried above as per comments but this does not work.

Comment: @Output is not a button click event. What are you trying to send back from child?

Comment: @AnjilDhamala My Parent has the button click event, when user press button click I want to read the value of 2 text box from first child component and read dropdown value from second child component. For example in above post how do I pass the value of message which is in my child component to my parent component.

Comment: @Pvl do we really have a event handler?

Comment: You could always create a shared data service that all the components could pull from and store data in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to pass some data as shown in your example, you can do like this

```
 Message: {{ child.message }}
 <app-child #child></app-child>
```

Comment: @karen, `<ct-child #child1></ct-metadata>`, can you try again after fixing this typo?

Comment: So I debugged it, and I can see that in my getDataFromChild function child1.message does has the text "Child Message!". But when I try to assign it to this.message = child1.message it says this.message is undefined. Anything wrong with that? Sorry I am just starting angular so this might be basic.

Comment: @karen, `this.message = child1.message;` has to be called after ngViewInit

Answer (score 4):

From what I understood after reading your post and comments below, you have a structure as
follows in your parent.component.html

```
 <app-child1></app-child1>
 <app-child2></app-child2>
 <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

When you click on the button, you want to get the data from child1 and child2 into the parent component.

So one way to solve this is using template reference variable,

```
<app-child1 #child1></app-child1>
<app-chidl2 #child2></app-child2>
<button type="button" (click)="getDataFromChild(child1,child2)">Click Me!</button>
```

Inside your parent typescript

```
getDataFromChild(child1,child2) {
  dataFromChild1 = child1.getData();
  dataFromChild2 = child2.getData();
}
```

Add getData() method in both the child1 and child2 component's ts and return the required data.

Comment: this does not work. See my updated code which I have used.

Comment: you are accessing message property of child, which is not there. Did you try child1.childmessage?

Comment: I have put your code in stackblitz, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jtymjj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts It's working fine. When you click the button, you will get the data in parent component.

Answer (score -2):

You talk to your child via `@Input()` and talk back to parent with `@Output`.

For your example, you get back the message from child using an `@Output`.

Here's your child component.

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Output() messageChanged: EventEmitter<string>();
  message = 'Hola Mundo!';

  constructor() { 
     this.messageChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.messageChanged.next(this.message);
  }
}
```

This is how your parent needs to look.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    Message: {{ message }}
    <app-child (messageChanged)="onMessageChange($event)"></app-child>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor() { }

  message:string;

  onMessageChange(message: string) {
    this.message = message;
  }
}
```